# can't get javascript program to work

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I'm working on a small dice game. In the game you click the mouse and the dice "rolls" and you get a new side of the dice. I just change the face of the die to match the number rolled. I can't seem to get it to work. When I click the mouse does the random number once but it's always the else. It equals 6 or greater and I can't get it to roll again. When you click the mouse it's supposed to create a random number between 0 5 and then the if statement that corresponds is supposed to show that side of the dice. I've been racking my brain for over an hour and can't seem to figure why it's not working. Can someone look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Please!

```
var dice = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400)
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  if (dice == 0) {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(0);
    ellipse(300, 200, 5, 5)
  } else if (dice == 1) {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(290, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 210, 5, 5);
  } else if (dice == 2) {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(290, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150)
    ellipse(290, 210, 5, 5)
  } else if (dice == 3) {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(290, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150)
    ellipse(290, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 190, 5, 5)
  } else if (dice == 4) {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(290, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150)
    ellipse(290, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(300, 200, 5, 5)
  } else {
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 200, 50, 50);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(290, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150)
    ellipse(290, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(310, 190, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(300, 210, 5, 5);
    fill(150);
    ellipse(300, 190, 5, 5)
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  dice = random(5);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever seriously thought about formatting your code?

Comment: What's random(5) here? Is it your own function or you want to use JS's Math.random function?

Comment: I just don't know what it is yet. I thought I could make the dice variable change to a random number between 0 and 5 by putting random(5). It works in other places, like fill(random(255),0,0). Thank you for the input. I will read up on math.random!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of `dice = random(5)`

```
dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
```

Math.random() returns a float number between 0 and 1
we multiple it by 6 then we have a number between 0 to 6
but it is float like 5.22554545
we use Math.floor to round it to the floor number, so it is an integer between 0 to 5 (and 5 itself). ===> 5.22324234 = 5

Comment: wow, that worked! Thank you so much. I don't understand why. I haven't made it that far in my studies yet, I guess. It might be asking a lot but can someone explain to me why  this works. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: some explanations added.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that for me. I getting the hang of it.